# Ionic 3: Modal Controller - Get component Instance

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am showing a Component `EventFeedbackComponent` via ModalController. Now I want to subscribe to a `Subject` in `EventFeedbackComponent`. How do I get access to the component instance, to achieve my goal.

My current code:

```
let modal   =   this.modalCtrl.create(EventFeedbackComponent);
modal.present();

// This is not working. Throws the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"
modal._component.feedbackSubmit.subscribe(feedbackResponse => {
    console.log(feedbackResponse);
});
```

Documentation didn't help in this regard: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

My use case:

- I have a list of Events in my `Service`, for which I need to get Feedback.
- `EventFeedbackComponent` has controls to get Feedback for a Single Event.
- Now, I show the EventFeedbackComponent to get feedback for First Event and listen for the event `feedbackSubmit` via `Subject`
- On submission of `feedback`, I show a Success Toast and switch my service variable in Service to show next event.
- Above point is repeated, till I get feedback for all Unreviewed events with the same Component shown via Model.

Comment: Can you tell me your use case here?

Comment: your design seems counterproductive. I suggest you use Subjects in a Service and not components

Comment: Updated my use case. Guess it should make more sense now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Option 1 Dismiss with params

Ionic modal component gives us the opportunity to close dialog with some arguments:

**modal.ts**

```
constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  this.prop = params.get('prop');
}

dismiss() {
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss({ test: '1' });
}
```

and in opener we should have:

**opener.ts**

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(TestComponent, { 'prop': 'prop1' });

modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  alert('Closed with data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

If it is not enough for you then

### Option 2 Communication through ViewContainer.emit

you can use `ViewController::emit` method to send data to opener

**modal.ts**

```
constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

sendFeedBack() {
  this.viewCtrl.emit({ someData: '2' });
}
```

**opener.ts**

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(TestComponent, { 'prop': 'prop1' });

modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  alert('Closed with data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
});

modal.present().then(result => {
  modal.overlay['subscribe']((z) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(z));
  })
});
```

### Option 3 Input callback

Since we can pass any parameter to modal then let's pass callback function:

**opener.ts**

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(TestComponent, { 
  'prop': 'prop1', 
  onFeedBack: (data) => {
    alert('Input callback' + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

**modal.ts**

```
onFeedBack: Function;

constructor(params: NavParams) {
  this.onFeedBack = params.get('onFeedBack');
}

sentThroughInputCallback() {
  this.onFeedBack({ s: '2' });
}
```

If you still want to get component instance then:

### Option 4 Get component instance

You can get component instance only after it has been created:

**opener.ts**

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(TestComponent, { 'prop': 'prop1' });

modal.present().then(result => {
  const testComp = modal.overlay['instance'] as TestComponent;
  testComp.feedbackSubmit.subscribe(() => {
    alert(1);
  })
});
```

Check it out on **[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/ZsiGZQvXv4m3nm1kbSJU?open=app%2Fpages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: Method 4 was what I was askingn for. There you have your +50. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tested method 4 in ionic 3.20.0. The "subscribe" method dosen't work, but you can replace it by "on" method and it work fine. Thanks bro, I love u